# How to do 'R CMD Sweave' in R 3.1.0?

Tags: r, sweave

**Summary.** Sweave works differently in R 3.1.0.

Until I upgraded to R 3.1.0, my Makefiles had e.g.

```
a.tex: a.Rnw
    R CMD Sweave $<
```

but with R 3.1.0 this doesn't run the R code within `a.Rnw` file.  As a workaround I now do e.g.

```
a.tex: a.Rnw
    R -e 'Sweave("$<")'
```

which works fine but I wonder why the old method fails.  (I've used the old method for all the R versions over the past two or three years.)

Comment: Check your installation. There is no reason `R CMD Sweave` should have stopped. I still have `Sweave` inside of `$RHOME/bin`.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not have R_HOME (as used in line 3 of Sweave) defined as an environment variable.  When I define it, everything works as before, i.e. I get not just the .tex file but also the R chunks get run.

Comment: Your `R` script will set that as long as you call the `R` script shipped with `R`. What does `type -p R` say, and what is in that script?

Comment: Thanks again.  I am on an OSX/Mavericks machine, and using the snowleopard
version of R 3.1.0, since the mavericks version would not install packages for
me (I tried 'tiff' and 'ncdf4' and 'mapplot').

As for your suggested tests, first

    `$type -p R`

yields

    `/usr/bin/R`

and second,

    `cat $(type -p R)`

yields, well this system will not permit me to include something that long but the md5 is `b7cc6a2b3ccf9bc27f8dd444c3caa8df`

Comment: I don't need the content, I suggest you try to understand why `/usr/bin/R` supposedly does not set `R_HOME`.  It all looks like some chopped salad you made of your installation. There is no question here as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into this some more.  I appreciate the help, and particularly the very speedy responses.